# RecyclerView provides fade in, fade out animations when item get added, deleted by default?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I was learning about RecyclerView using online tutorials, youtube, and ebooks. I have found that **By default, RecyclerView instantiates and uses an instance of DefaultItemAnimator** So it provides animations for add, remove operations.

But in AndroidHive, Slidenerd youtube channel and lot of other online sites, they use the below code.

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

I didn't understand, why are they using the above code?

1. Is there any need for using the above code?
2. if yes, What doc means by default?

I have searched a lot but I can't find any proper information or I can not fully understand because I am weak in English too.

links:
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: You don't need to assign a `DefaultItemAnimator` yourself - it is, unsurprisingly, the "default" item animator. It wont do any harm, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: Well perhaps AndroidHive doesn't know it and provides it by code. Stick to the docs to be safer.

Comment: Thanks for informing that no need for above code. 2 days gone for research.